# equivalent categories, $\operatorname{FinVect}_K$

Tags: category-theory

> Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the category of vector spaces with finite dimension. Show that it exists a small category $\mathcal{C}$ which is equivalent to $\mathcal{V}$.

If we take the category $\operatorname{Mat}_K=\mathcal{C}$, with the naturals $0,1,2,\dotso$ as objects and where a morphism $n\to m$ is a $m\times n$ matrix over a fixed field $K$ are.

The identity $n\to n$ is the identity matrix and the composition of morphisms given by the multiplication of matrices, which has all the required properties.

By definition I need two functors $F:\operatorname{Mat}_K\to\mathcal{V}$ and $G:\mathcal{V}\to\operatorname{Mat}_K$ and two natural transformations $\tau:F\circ G\simeq \operatorname{id}_\mathcal{V}$, $\eta: G\circ F\simeq \operatorname{id}_{\operatorname{Mat}_K}$, such that for every object $M\in\operatorname{Ob}(\operatorname{Mat}_K)$ and $V\in\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{V})$ the morphism $\tau_M: F\circ G(M)\to M$, and $\eta_V: G\circ F(V)\to V$ are isomorphisms.

I tried this:

$F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{V}$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $F(n):=K^n$ and for a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ let $F(A):K^n\to K^m$ with $x\mapsto Ax$.

This is indeed a functor, since $A(Bx)=(AB)x$ and we have the identity matrix $I$ as neutral element: $Ix=x$

But now I would have to construct a functor $G:\mathcal{V}\to \mathcal{C}$, but I doubt that this is so easy.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Equivalent *how*? Are you asking for some "canonical $n$-dimensional vector spaces"? That seems *really easy*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Equivalent as categories. I gave the definition in the body text. Or do I understand you wrong?

Comment: Are you familiar with [skeletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(category_theory))? Every category has skeleton(s) and is equivalent with each skeleton. This can be proved in general setting and then be applied to your case. It then only remains to be shown that the skeleton in your case is small.

Comment: @drhab No, I am not. We only defined very little in category theory in a course about algebraic topology. We only defined 'category', 'isomorphism', 'functor' and 'natural transformation'. Also we did not proof anything.

Comment: It is an important topic especially if it concerns equivalences. Actually two categories are equivalent if and only if their skeletons are isomorphic.

Comment: I have answered in the line of skeletons. It also contains the construction of a functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construction of functor from category to one of its skeletons.

---

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category.

On objects we have the relation of "being isomorphic" which is evidently an equivalence relation.

From every equivalence class choose a representative.

If $R\subseteq\mathsf{Ob}(\mathcal C)$ denotes this collection of representatives then let $\mathcal S$ be the full subcategory that has $R$ as its collection of objects.

Then $\mathcal S$ is a so-called skeleton of $\mathcal C$.

For object $c$ in $\mathcal C$ let $F(c)$ be the representative of $c$ which is an object of $\mathcal S$. Then $F$ can be looked at as the object function of a functor. To make it indeed a functor we must find for every arrow $f:c\to d$ in $\mathcal C$ an arrow $F(f):F(c)\to F(d)$ in an appropriate way.

For this choose for every object $c$ an isomorphism $i_c:c\to F(c)$.

Then prescribe $F$ on arrows by stating that $f:c\to d$ is mapped by $F$ to $i_d\circ f\circ i_c^{-1}:F(c)\to F(d)$.

In my (favorite) notation: $$\left[c\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}d\right]\stackrel{F}{\mapsto}\left[F\left(c\right)\stackrel{i_{d}\circ f\circ i_{c}^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}F\left(d\right)\right]$$

Then it is not difficult to verify that $F$ respects identities and composition whence is a functor.

Actually $F$ is an equivalence and $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal S$ are equivalent categories.

---

This can be applied in your case and it remains to prove that there $\mathcal S$ is small.

Answer (score 1):

For each finite dimensional vector space pick a basis. Then send each finite dimensional vector space to its dimension, and each linear map to the matrix representing it with respect to the bases chosen for its source and target.

Comment: Thanks. It is not clear to me however at the moment. I tried to give one functor. Is this one correct?

Comment: @Cornman Your $F$ is correct, I'm describing the corresponding $G$.